# Bootstrap input group addon not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code: http://www.bootply.com/iR1SvOyEGH

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Company Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.test.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

My understanding is the input-group-addon should sit inline with the input box and be to the right but instead it sits below the input box taking up 100% width.

Can anyone please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Could you get it works? I have the same error... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap documentation states that the `input-group-addon` class must be used within a `input-group`, while you are using a `form-group`.

```
   <form>
      <label for="inputEmail">Company Name</label>
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-addon">.test.com</span>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </form>
```

See this for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TLtQU/3/

**EDIT:** The input-group should not include the label, the label should be outside of the input-group for proper results.

Comment: Thank you, that's better but the addon is still taller than it should be with your code as it seems to extend up to the label http://jsfiddle.net/TLtQU/1/

Comment: And for full styling/alignment, you can/should put the label and the input-group both within one form-group

Answer (score 0):

Create a style:

```
.input-group-inline {
    display: inline-flex; 
    width: auto; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And add this to the class input-group