# HTML, Bootstrap3 - Inline form, how to set the field length?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I have the following form but I am having some trouble to make all the fields of the same length. As a matter of fact, is the code too long? I am a begginer so I don't know if I am repeating a lot of code.

[image]

Here is the html piece:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class = "panel-heading">
                    Informações do Imóvei 
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-inline">   
                        <label class="control-label">{{anuncioForm.tipo_imovel.label}}</label>
                        <p>Selecione o tipo do seu imóvel</p>
                        <select class="form-control control-label" 
                        id="id_{{ anuncioForm.tipo_imovel.name }}" 
                        name="anuncioForm.tipo_imovel.name">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                            <option value="Casa">Casa</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento">Apartamento</option>
                            <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleTextarea">Descrição do imóvel</label>
                        <p>Descreva com o máximo de detalhes o seu imóvel</p>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p><b>Características do imóvel</b></p>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.quartos.label }}</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.quartos.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.quartos.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>         
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.suites.label }}</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.suites.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.suites.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.label }}</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>  
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.label }}</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>   
                    </div>   
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-inline">   
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.area_total.label }}</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_total.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_total.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-inline">   
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Data de Construção</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.data_construcao.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.data_construcao.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                        <p>Insira o ano em que o imóvel foi construído</p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p><b>Preço de Venda</b></p>
                    <div class="form-inline">   
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>R$</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_venda.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_venda.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p><b>Preço do Aluguel</b></p>
                    <div class="form-inline">   
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon"><label>R$</label></span>
                          <input class="form-control" 
                          id="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_aluguel.name }}" 
                          name="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_aluguel.name }}" 
                          type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
```

So, what do you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of bootstrap grids col-xx-xx or adjust your input width externally.

Better read this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25017998/6107715

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style> 
/*.input-group{min-width: 200px; max-height: 500px;}*/
</style>
</head>



<div class="panel panel-default">
      
      <div class="panel-body">
        
        <br>
        
        <p><b>Características do imóvel</b></p>
        
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.quartos.label }}</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.quartos.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.quartos.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>         
    
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.suites.label }}</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.suites.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.suites.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>

   
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group  ">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.label }}</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.banheiros.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <br>  
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.label }}</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_construida.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>   
        </div>   

        <br>
        
        <div class="form-inline">   
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>{{ anuncioForm.area_total.label }}</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_total.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.area_total.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <br>
       
        <div class="form-inline">   
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>Data de Construção</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.data_construcao.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.data_construcao.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>
            <p>Insira o ano em que o imóvel foi construído</p>
        </div>
       <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
          <label class="input-group-addon" for="exampleInput">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
      </form>
        <br>
       
        <p><b>Preço de Venda</b></p>
        <div class="form-inline">   
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>R$</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_venda.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_venda.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p><b>Preço do Aluguel</b></p>
        <div class="form-inline">   
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><label>R$</label></span>
              <input class="form-control" 
              id="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_aluguel.name }}" 
              name="id_{{ anuncioForm.preco_aluguel.name }}" 
              type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are putting  on every input. it should be :

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInput">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
</form>
```

Then, apply your width settings to the class

`.form-group`

this will adjust the width of the label and input to match as they will auto adjust.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I do it the label goes to the top of the field. So it does not work ..